# Is \algorithmicand a standard command in the algorithmic package?

Tags: macros, algorithms

I have a tex file created by someone else which redefines commands of the algorithmic package to translate them to the Portuguese language. For example:

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{enquanto}}
```

Is used to replace the word **while** by ***enquanto***, which is the translation of while to Portuguese.

However, I am getting errors when I invoke `\renewcommand` for the following lines:

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicand}{\textbf{e}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicor}{\textbf{ou}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicto}{\textbf{até}}
```

Here's the error for the first line:

```
! LaTeX Error: \algorithmicand undefined.
```

Do I get this error because `\algorithmicand`, `\algorithmicor`, and `\algorithmicto` are not included the algorithmic package? Is it ok for me to use the `\newcommand` instead of `\renewcommand` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may look up the definition of a command `\foo` (including if it is defined at all) with

```
\show\foo
```

A test for `\algorithmicand` reveals that it is indeed defined by the `algorithmic` package. Redefining it also works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\show\algorithmicand

\renewcommand{\algorithmicand}{\textbf{e}}

\algorithmicand

\end{document}
```

You should provide a minimum example that produces the error described by you.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the `algorithmic` package helps. Earlier versions, such as [that one of 2006/06/02](http://ctan.binkerton.com/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithmic.sty), don't provide that command yet, as you can see following the link. The current version defines

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicand}{\textbf{and}}
```

and further similar commands right after `\algorithmicreturn`, which is already contained in the older version.